# Static Component Not Getting Refresh in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have a profile component which remains static on the page and is only visible to the user using *ngIf when he logs in, so as the user logs in, I also call the service of the profile component to get the user details and the parameters used for binding are getting updated, but the View is not getting updated with the updated value.

Say for example the user name and his unique id is not getting bound to the view after the login service is called.

To call the profile service, I have imported the profile component ts.

**import { ProfileComponent } from 'src/app/components/profile/profile.component';**
in login component and have called the profile service 
**this.getUserDetails('servicePath')**
on success of login service

Also the *ngIf is not getting updated if the conditions are set to true in the profile component.

Kindly assist me on the same.

**Profile TS Code**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/service/api.service';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: "app-points-block",
  templateUrl: './points-block.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./points-block.component.css']

})
export class PointsBlockComponent implements OnInit {
  userProfileData : any = []; 
  constructor(private _router: Router, private http: Http,private apiService: ApiService) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUserPoints(userPointsUrl);
  }

  /*** GET USER PROFILE POINTS ***/
  getUserPoints(userPointsUrl){

    this.apiService.postService(userPointsUrl, userProfileObj)
      .subscribe(
        response => {

          if (response.Code == 200) {
            this.userProfileData = response.Data[0];
          } else {
            this.userProfileData = response.Error;
          }
      });
  }
}
```

**Login TS Code :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/service/api.service';
import { LoginService } from 'src/app/service/login.service';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import {Router, ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
import {FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from '../../app.component';
import { PointsBlockComponent } from 'src/app/components/points-block/points-block.component';

import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Component({
  providers:[PointsBlockComponent, PollsComponent, LeaderboardComponent],
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private loginSerive: LoginService, private http: Http,private apiService: ApiService, private router: Router, private _appComp: AppComponent,
    private _pointBlockComp : PointsBlockComponent) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  /*** INITIAGE LOGIN FORM CONTROLLER ***/
  loginForm = new FormGroup({
    'username': new FormControl("john.Makwane02@postboxcommunications.com", [Validators.required]), 
    'password': new FormControl("User@1234", [Validators.required])
  });

  /*** SUBMIT LOGIN FORM ***/
  loginFromSubmit(){
    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
      let loginFromData = {
        "username": this.loginForm.controls['username'].value,
        "password": this.loginForm.controls['password'].value,
      }

      this.loginSerive.validateUser(environment.submitLoginForm, loginFromData)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          if (response.Code == 200) {
              this._pointBlockComp.ngOnInit();
          }
        });
    }else{
      this.validateAllFormFields(this.loginForm);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: Can you create a small stackblitz for this?

Comment: i have updated the question with the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it makes no sense to provide a component inside another component. Now since I cannot see the html of both the elements I assume that you want to show the profile component after the user has logged in. In this case you need to create two routes.

```
export routes: Route[] = [
 {
   path: 'login',
   component: LoginComponent,
   canActivate: [AnonymousGuard] // This will be a service that implements CanActivate and return true only if the user is not logged in otherwise logged in user will also have access to the login router and that makes no sense.
 },
{
  path: 'profile',
  component: PointsBlockComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard] // this will a service that will return true only when the user is logged in.
}
];
```

Let me know if this not the usecase and I will provide you with the solution according to your usecase.

Comment: Hi, The profile component is the side widget which is called only once and is not displayed to the user if he is not logged in. Once he is logged in the sidebar gets visable with the updated value.

say for eg. we have a landing page where all the data are visible and if the user want to interact with the site he will have to login. and then only the side bar which is fixed and does not reload is visible to the user.

**app** component contain html

'<div><app-sidebar></app-sidebar><router-outlet #o="outlet" (activate)="changeOfRoutes()"></router-outlet></div>'

Comment: In that case you should separate out the modules in your project AuthModule(all non logged in related stuff) and DashboardModule(all logged in related stuff) ideally. 

https://medium.com/@michelestieven/organizing-angular-applications-f0510761d65a

the sidebar component should go into the core module as described in the above link. I think after reading the above blog you will get a better understanding of what I am trying to state. Happy to help!